# c++ make a class knowing about another object

Tags: c++, pointers

if I have something like this:

```
class A: public Mother{
public:
    A(B b){ b_pointer = &b; };
    void update() override { int value = b_pointer->getSomething(); };
private:
    B* b_pointer;
};


class B{
public:
   void update(//parameters);
   int getSomething();
};
```

then in another part of the program, let's say in the class C, both a B and A object are created.

```
B b_object;
b_object(//attributes of C needed as parameters);
A a_object(b_object);
```

so, will `b_pointer` refers to `b_object`?
if inside a method of A I use `b_pointer->getSomething()`; will it always refer to b_object?

because i need to update `a_object` making it knowing about `b_object`, but I can't write the void `A::update()` method like `update(B& b) {b.doThings()}` since `A::update` overrides a `Mother` method and in the class C i have a vector of `Mothers*` to be updated.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: No, it will not be. The pointer will be pointing to the former parameter to the constructor, which is already destroyed, is just a distant memory, and the pointer is pointing to a destroyed object. Using the pointer, at this point, is undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks sam.. as i suspected, so are there any solutions?

Comment: @LauroRossi be careful, your `A(B b){ b_pointer = &b; };` it's a dangling pointer. Attento.

Comment: The constructor of `A` would need to accept the `B` by ref/pointer

Comment: So you have a class C which contains a vector of pointers to Mother which you update from within class C. But, some derived classes (like A) need an instance of B to perform their update correctly? And other derived classes do not need that instance of B?

Comment: Try this instead:  `A(B& b){ b_pointer = &b; };`